# How to get by default India selected in react js?

Tags: reactjs

How can I get by default India selected.
Here is my code-

```
  <CountryDropdown  id="UNIQUE_ID" className='YOUR_CSS_CLASS' defaultValue={'IN'} handleChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)}></CountryDropdown>
```

Comment: We need to know more about the component CountryDropdown in order to help you

Comment: Can you try passing the full country name? India